# Redux state in component not updating after action dispatch, but shows up in redux devtools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am running this piece of code when an item in my menu is clicked.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'react-dropdown-tree-select/dist/styles.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import '../../../css/tree.css';
import updateSelectedTree from '../../../redux/actions/menu/updateSelectedTree';
import {updateTraceName} from '../../../redux/actions/plot/traceActions';
import { removeRenameProp, pushRenameProp } from '../../../redux/actions/menu/renameActions'
import resolveTraceName from '../../../utils/resolveTraceName';
import MeasureTreeSelector from './MeasureTreeSelector';
class MeasureTreeSelectorContainer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<MeasureTreeSelector
            isSingle={false}
            tags={this.props.tags}
            selected={this.props.selected}
            handleTreeChange={this.handleTreeChange}
        > </MeasureTreeSelector>);

    }
    handleTreeChange = (curr, selected) => {
        console.log(curr)
        // Get the order of the selected items
        const selectedProperty = [...curr.path.split("/").splice(1), curr.value]

        if(curr.checked) {
            this.props.pushRenameProp(selectedProperty)
        } else {
            this.props.removeRenameProp(selectedProperty)
        }
       console.log(this.props.rename_props)
       this.props.updateSelectedTree(this.props.rename_props)
    }

    updateTraces = () => {
       this.props.measures.forEach(element => {
           const newName = resolveTraceName(element, this.props.rename_props);
           console.log(newName)
           this.props.updateTraceName(newName, element.id)
       }) 
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state.menuReducer)
    return {
        tags: state.menuReducer.tags,
        selected: state.menuReducer.selected,
        measures: state.menuReducer.json,
        rename_props: state.menuReducer.rename_props
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    updateSelectedTree,
    updateTraceName,
    removeRenameProp,
    pushRenameProp
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MeasureTreeSelectorContainer);
```

pushRenameProp and removeRenameProp are synchronous actions that are dispatched that update rename_props. These reducers don't mutate the state but create a new one which means there should be an update in the component.

```js
export function pushRenameProp(prop) {
    return {
        type:'PUSH_RENAME_PROP',
        payload: prop
    }
}

export function removeRenameProp(prop) {
    return {
        type:'REMOVE_RENAME_PROP',
        payload: prop
    }
}
 case 'PUSH_RENAME_PROP':{
            console.log(action.payload)
            return {
                ...state,
                rename_props: [...state.rename_props,action.payload]
            }
        }
        case 'REMOVE_RENAME_PROP': {
            return {
                ...state,
                rename_props: state.rename_props.filter((e,i) => {
                    return JSON.stringify(e) != JSON.stringify(action.payload) 
                })
            }
        }
```

When I execute this action, the devtools show that the redux state has updated, but the code shows that rename_props is empty.

It seems to be that the component props are one state change behind the redux state

Comment: Can you share full related code?

Comment: @tmhao2005 what other code is needed?

Comment: Full component and action. Or are you able to set up a codesandbox?

Comment: I am not able to set up a code sandbox , however I have added the full component code and action to the post

Answer (score 0):

This line `this.props.updateSelectedTree(this.props.rename_props)` sets the `rename_props` as they were on before setting them.
So it just negates the change.

You could do this in a thunk:

```
export function pushRenameProp(prop) {
    return function (dispatch, getState) {
        dispatch({
            type:'PUSH_RENAME_PROP',
            payload: prop
        })
        const state = getState();
        
        return dispatch(updateSelectedTree(state.menuReducer.rename_props)
    }
}
```

To ensure that the `updateSelectedTree` has the newest state.

*code is not tested, but I think you get the gist of this.

But also, maybe, `updateSelectedTree` is not needed at all.
You change the state by just push/remove, why update?

Comment: I use updateSelectedTree to keep the UI component controlled by the redux state and it doesn't have an affect on the rename_props.
When I get rid of updateSelectedTree, I still have same issue as before

Comment: @Darruma can you also post `updateSelectedTree` code? I cannot understand what you mean, connect is used to control the component by the redux state, `updateSelectedTree` is an action, no? just like push/remove.. The state changes by actions, connect subscribes to state changes. and binds action creators